# Read URL parameter - Starts with #

Tags: angular

I have integrated `google-api` in my **angular application**.
Generally, the query parameter will start with **?=** but **google returned URL** after authentication starts with **#** so I couldn't able read the url parameter.

**Sample returned URL:**

```
http://localhost:4200/oauth/google-docs#scope=email%20profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly%20openid%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics&id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ijc4M2VjMDMxYzU5ZTExZjI1N2QwZWMxNTcxNGVmNjA3Y2U2YTJhNmYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJhY2NvdW50cy5nb29nbGUuY29tIiwiYXpwIjoiMjUzNjIyMDIyODQ3LWljaG5mNHA5aXEzMjBtc2hxOHVuMHU3NzRqM3JyM3BxLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiMjUzNjIyMDIyODQ3LWljaG5mNHA5aXEzMjBtc2hxOHVuMHU3NzRqM3JyM3BxLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tIiwic3ViIjoiMTE4MjM5MDE3NjE4NTAwNDQ0MzAyIiwiZW1haWwiOiJzYXRoaWFtb29ydGh5Lm5pQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjp0cnVlLCJpYXQiOjE2MTEyMDUxNjIsImV4cCI6MTYxMTIwODc2MiwianRpIjoiOTZmMzc0OWFmMzRjNDhkYmI4YTI0ODg3YTI4YTRjMjA1YmZjYzhlMyJ9.H56V0v0EM9QR1iYAnctfBLaMdvhtxGxNWXXCWdNJQcpj6pLPJm_TELLDCQD-Pbf9wI1gK4XDflwLabCSSj2ZxTQP00-gPzym7wHhQg6Jvlls_h98HvfE6FWq4pZE0rBZ9eYQ1ExyCs29OPcF8SXtgn3JvM1dtEP7Y1yJ8JeZBSC6EH5oDGHzsz4TUWZhnr3coJdzbatj7LOW8I4_9Q8HzATfpCEJzolMoRcrIMlBii7K6bYMvTSCO0t7KlibucKaH0_HBj-MKJ3fFHKXmBeAm8gOMvv2uC5vWdTiVv0WFeZKZ4EehTDjP7WFeg7eyfhYp-TxrfvAJE3nxBnEx8G39A&login_hint=AJDLj6JUa8yxXrhHdWRHIV0S13cAVabJpG7Wvu9kahbHz74sfe70f99ozWADGi1j3da_ocb32QvRp7hTdX0b9Lx9x8oHgfQHlw&client_id=253622022847-ichnf4p9iq320mshq8un0u774j3rr3pq.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

Any solution to read the url parameter?

Comment: Try like this - this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).queryParams[key] || ''; Hope it helps!

Comment: Tried now, not working. returns undefined.

Comment: can you please  share complete code thread where you are using it

Comment: @Shakthifuture, you have imported Router right ?

Comment: yes @KrunalShah, this.router.url working but while queryParams it returns undefined.

Comment: share your code please..

Comment: @KrunalShah, this is the code i used in ngOninit method `console.log(this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url).queryParams['scope']);`

Comment: Refer this - https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-6-url-parameters-860db789db85 using ActivatedRoute.

Comment: @KrunalShah, I already had experience on using ActivatedRoute, it is working when url parameter start with ?=, here url parameter start with #= so it not reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant because it a hash (or fragment), not a query params, so you need to parse it if you wish to have it as query params:

```
let hash = window.location.hash;
let googleParams = new URLSearchParams(hash).replace('#','');

console.log(googleParams.get('scope'));
```

Comment: windows.location.hash throws undefined

Comment: window without s @Shakthifuture